# Is x += 1 more efficient than x = x + 1?

Tags: c, performance, increment

In `x = x + 1`, is `x` evaluated twice? If so, does that mean in `x += 1`, `x` is only evaluated once? How are the two expressions evaluated in terms of compiler intermediate code?

For example, `x++` could mean : take the location of `x`, load the contents of `x` into a register, and increment the value of `x` in memory.

Also I have read that `x += 1` is useful when `x` is not a simple variable, but an expression involving an array. Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: This sounds like a lot of unfounded assumptions, in particular the title. I don’t see a reason why one should be more efficient than the other and I’m reasonably confident that it’s not the case on most C compilers.

Comment: A compiler worth the money you paid for it will compile both expressions to the same object code. If you are worried about performance: **measure**, measure different code, different compilation flags, different resource usage, different everything.

Comment: Do you know that x += 1 is more efficient than x = x + 1?  Have you looked at the generated object code?

Comment: Maybe this was applicable to older compilers..I am curious why one could be more efficient than the other in an older compiler...I read about this in a book called "Deep C Secrets".

Comment: How about finding some books that are not 17 years old?

Comment: There is conceivably a difference in C++ (if `x` is a UDT), but there should be no difference in C.

Comment: Ok..so if x is a user defined type, how would x =+1 be more efficient?

Comment: Asking about UDTs is a different question. This question is about C.

Comment: Not only is it a duplicate; this question has a false assumption in the subject line.

Comment: @David: Yes, that was my point...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most compilers these would be identical

Comment: what about the older compilers? which do not optimize as much as the newer ones..why are they evaluated differently?

Comment: If the compiler is inefficient, it may ignore the fact that x is referred to twice and load it and then perform the incrementing operation on the loaded value.

Comment: and what about the comment about arrays?

Comment: again - a good compiler will be able to produce the same code, but an inefficient one might have more trouble with more complex expressions such as those involving array members

Answer (score 21):

Just to give you a "real-world" example, consider this program:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    i += 1;
    i++;
    i = i + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with GCC, in Darwin 11 with the following flags:

- `-S` stop in assembler
- `-m32` to 32-bit platform, just to simplify things a bit

Will generate the following program, except for the comments and blank lines which I added. Take a look specially in the comments.

```
        .section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl  _main
        .align  4, 0x90
_main:
        pushl   %ebp              # cdecl function stuff
        movl    %esp, %ebp        #
        subl    $12, %esp         # get room for variables    
        movl    $0, -12(%ebp)     # i = 0;

        ; i += 1
        movl    -12(%ebp), %eax   # load i in register a
        addl    $1, %eax          # add 1 to register a
        movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)   # store it back in memory

        ; i++
        movl    -12(%ebp), %eax   #
        addl    $1, %eax          # just the same
        movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)   #

        ; i = i + 1
        movl    -12(%ebp), %eax   #
        addl    $1, %eax          # just the same
        movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)   #

        movl    $0, -8(%ebp)
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        addl    $12, %esp
        popl    %ebp
        ret

.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't marked as the answer, since it provides proof and not just an opinion.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Also do we find any difference in other compilers or does it follow the same pattern ?

Comment: @SanVed Thanks. Hard to tell, considering the amount of compilers. But any compiler with a decent development will probably contain this "intelligence". Compilers are not just direct translators from high to low level, there is a whole science involved and examples like this one are among the most basic and first elements of this science. So any modern and major compiler should include it.

Answer (score 8):

> Why is x += 1 more efficient than x = x+1?

It isn't.

> Why is x++ more efficient than x += 1?

It isn't.

---

The reason for preferring `x += 1` to `x = x+1` comes about when `x` is replaced with a much longer identifier, or perhaps a field in a class or struct. In that situation, the `x += 1` version is more readable and even more importantly avoids the pitfalls of repeating yourself.

Answer (score 3):

So there are already some questions that cover what you're asking here:

[x=x+1 vs. x +=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808062/x-x1-vs-x-1)

[Incrementing: x++ vs x += 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509707/incrementing-x-vs-x-1)

[Which is faster? ++, += or x + 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477944/which-is-faster-or-x1)

The bottom line is that in most *but not all* languages the compiler is going to make them identical anyway, so there's no difference in efficiency. The questions above go into a fair bit of detail on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc, you can get the assembler code with `gcc -S foo.c`. I tried it with `x += 1` and `x = x + 1` and it was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because it takes 4 characters to write rather than 5.

This is the only way in which `x+=1` is "more efficient" than `x=x+1`. However the `+=` operator does have a few other advantages, like the fact that `(x)+=1` works in macros where `x` is an expression that may have side effects which you want to avoid evaluating more than once...