# Why is the behavior of assignment operation in while loop's conditional expression different? (CPP)

Tags: c++, while-loop, variable-assignment

I tried out `x+=1`, `x=x+1` inside the while loop's condition.

```
x = 0 // Initial value of x
```

*1st case*

```
while(x+=1 && x < 5){
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

*2nd case*

```
while(x=x+1 && x < 5){
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

The first case and second case are puzzling. What is the difference in the behavior of `x+=1` and `x=x+1` that both go into infinite loop (Because of short circuiting). But the value of x in the 1st case is stuck at 1.

Any thoughts ?

According to [Is x += 1 more efficient than x = x + 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471891/is-x-1-more-efficient-than-x-x-1), most compilers (good) optimize and do the exact same thing.

Compiler that I am using  - *gcc version 5.4.0*

Comment: *I am assuming the ++ operator does not return anything* Why assume?  Why not look it up and see what it really does?

Comment: "I am assuming the ++ operator does not return anything" You are assuming wrong.

Comment: If `++` operator "did not return anything", you wouldn't be able to use it as an operand of `&&` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bewilderment stems from a lack of parentheses. Your expressions are, in order, equivalent to the following:

```
(x++) && (x < 5)     // First case
x+=(1 && (x < 5))    // Second case
x=((x+1) && (x < 5)) // Third case
```

Along with implicit conversions and so on, this yields the behavior you are seeing.

*This is why we use parentheses, and enable warnings when compiling.*

Answer (score 0):

`x++` is an expression that increments `x`; its value is the old value of x. So with this code

```
int x = 0;
std::cout << x++ << 'n';
```

the output will be 0. Try it.

In the expression `x++ && x < 5`,  `x++` has the value 0, and 0 is treated as false. It's the left-hand side of the `&&` operator, and because it's false, the right-hand side is not evaluated; the value of the expression is `false`. Try it.

The rest of the examples all increment the value of `x`, so in the test, the value of `x` is 1, which is treated as `true` for the `&&` operator. That's the difference between the `x++` in the first example and the `x += 1` and the `x = x + 1` in the second and third. To make the first one act like the others, change it to `++x && x < 5`. In that case, `++x` increments `x`, and the value of the expression is the result of the increment. So with

```
int x = 0;
std::cout << ++x << '\n';
```

the output will be 1. Try it.