# Will a+=1 be faster than a = a+1 in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I'm not sure whether it's the same in Python.

Has anyone tried that before?

http://docs.python.org/library/operator#operator.iadd

Comment: I doubt that `a+=1` will be faster than `a=a+1` *in C*.

Comment: Those do exactly the same thing, why would there be a difference?

Comment: @Esailija: They do the same thing only if `a` doesn't implement its own `__iadd__`.

Comment: @Esailija Have you seen this before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808062/x-x1-vs-x-1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There hardly is a difference in the work python performs for either statement:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def inplace_add():
...     a = 0
...     a += 1
... 
>>> def add_and_assign():
...     a = 0
...     a = a + 1
... 
>>> dis.dis(inplace_add)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             12 INPLACE_ADD         
             13 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(add_and_assign)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             12 BINARY_ADD          
             13 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

The difference is a `INPLACE_ADD` versus a `BINARY_ADD`.

The resulting timings are too close to call which one would be faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('inplace_add', 'from __main__ import inplace_add', number=10000000)
0.32667088508605957
>>> timeit.timeit('add_and_assign', 'from __main__ import add_and_assign', number=10000000)
0.34172606468200684
```

So, in python, the difference is negligible. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Great answer (I didn't know about the `dis` module, so thank you). One consideration is that the speed of execution may be affected by the other processes running at a given time. My approach was therefore to run both 1 million times in a function and compare the execution speed in `cProfile` many times (see below). I agree that the difference is negligible.

Comment: I don't really understand why using `a += 1` will call in-place operation when `a` is an immutable object, `integer`. AFAIK, integer is an immutable object in Python. The in-place operation should only make sense if an object is a mutable. Can someone explain to me? Thank you.

Comment: @LionLai: The in-place operation is a _statement_, meaning it is part of the language, and works for *any* variable, whatever the type, provided that it supports the 'regular' operation (`+` here).  The integer remains immutable, but the number of bytecode steps that the interpreter has to perform is fewer. It works because integers support the `+` addition operation.

Answer (score 6):

Nope

```
>>> bar = timeit.Timer("a += 1", "a = 0")
>>> bar.timeit(number=1000000)
0.064391136169433594
>>> bar = timeit.Timer("a = a + 1", "a = 0")
>>> bar.timeit(number=1000000)
0.064393997192382812
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yep, but the difference is marginal.

```
>>> timeit.Timer('x += 1', 'x = 0').timeit(10**8)
5.7387330532073975
>>> timeit.Timer('x = x + 1', 'x = 0').timeit(10**8)
6.04801607131958
>>> timeit.Timer('x += 1', 'x = 0').timeit(10**8)
5.790481090545654
>>> timeit.Timer('x = x + 1', 'x = 0').timeit(10**8)
6.083467960357666
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a slightly different approach using the `cProfile` module:

```
$ python -m cProfile test.py 
     4 function calls in 0.397 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.397    0.397 test.py:2(<module>)
        1    0.205    0.205    0.205    0.205 test.py:2(add1)
        1    0.192    0.192    0.192    0.192 test.py:6(add2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}




aaron@zebrafish:~/pyad$ cat test.py 
def add1(a):
    for x in xrange(10 ** 6):
        a += 1

def add2(a):
    for x in xrange(10 ** 6):
        a = a + 1

add1(0)
add2(0)
```

After about 20 runs I would conclude that add2 (using `a = a + 1`) was very slightly faster, but not in all cases (perhaps try it with a greater number of loops). This is probably not the best heuristic, but I figure a greater number of repetitions with larger and larger numbers should indicate a performance difference.

EDIT - results for 10 ** 9 calls:

```
    1  216.119  216.119  216.119  216.119 test.py:2(add1)
    1  195.364  195.364  195.364  195.364 test.py:6(add2)
```